# where to intialize variables

Tags: loops, sentinel

we are using a nested loop and it is showing us that we have not initialized our variables.

we tried initializing variable both in and out of the loop but it says it was either not initialized or already initialized.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LargeSmallAverage
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int inputNumber, smallest, largest, sum,count;
        sum=0;
        count=0;

        System.out.println("Enter a number, entering a negative number 
will end the program");
        inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (inputNumber >=0)

        {
            if (inputNumber>sum){
                int largest= inputNumber;
                int smallest= sum;
            }
            else if (sum<inputNumber){
                int largest=sum;
                int smallest=inputNumber;
            }   
            sum += inputNumber;
            count++;
        System.out.println("Enter another number");
        inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        double average = sum/count;
        System.out.println("The largest number is "+largest+", the smallest number is "+smallest+", and the average of all positive numbers entered is "+average+".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have already defined smallest and largest in line 7**

int inputNumber, smallest, largest, sum, count;

**and then you are still defining smallest and largest in if and else if.**
Corrected code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargeSmallAverage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputNumber = 0, smallest = 0, largest = 0, sum, count;
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter a number, entering a negative number will end the program");
        inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (inputNumber >= 0)

        {
            if (inputNumber > sum) {
                largest = inputNumber;
                smallest = sum;
            } else if (sum < inputNumber) {
                largest = sum;
                smallest = inputNumber;
            }
            sum += inputNumber;
            count++;
            System.out.println("Enter another number");
            inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        double average = sum / count;
        System.out.println("The largest number is " + largest + ", the smallest number is " + smallest
                + ", and the average of all positive numbers entered is " + average + ".");
    }
}
```